# Why does cache:clear not wipe all Redis keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, laravel-8

I'm trying to figure out how the `php artisan cache:clear` command works in relation to my Redis data store. I can store keys in Redis and run cache:clear and the Redis keys are not wiped, even though I'm using Redis as my cache.

For example I can set a key like:

```php
Redis::set('foo', 'bar');
Redis::get('foo'); // bar
```

Listing out the keys with `Cache::getRedis()->keys("*");` will even show my "foo" key. These persist even if I clear the cache with `php artisan cache:clear`.

My question is if the cache:clear command doesn't delete my Redis data what does it do? Are there any commands in Laravel that I need to watch out for if I do use Redis as a data store? I don't want to rely on Redis data but then wipe it on accident..

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` is clearing the cache directory created by Laravel, which is typically located under `/storage/framework/cache/data/`. Redis is it's own instance, independent from PHP. If you need more info about clearing Redis, you can take a look here https://phoenixnap.com/kb/clear-redis-cache

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Redis as your cache driver, then to set keys use the `Cache` facade directly

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;


Cache::put('key', 'value');
```

Ps: To clear the cache keys of your app you can use `Cache::flush();`

As far as I understand, Laravel prefix all the values stored with a config key. So, this may explain why after you clearing the cache it still have your values set while using the Redis class instead.

Comment: Okay interesting. So it seems like even if Redis is the cache driver `Cache::put` and `Redis::set` are not the same thing. Thankfully Redis::set values won't be impacted by cache clearing operations, even if Redis is the cache driver :)

Comment: @connorLeech that's my assumption, yes. Could you please verify if this is the case and comment back? It's interesting :)

Comment: Yes it is. But I'm not sure how to view the redis cache keys